# No attributes in backbone model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, marionette, rabl

I'm looking at an example from `http://www.backbonerails.com/` which looks exactly the same.
Let me just draw you a picture from my app:

### routes:

`routes.rb:`

```
Mario::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'application#index'

  resources :conferences
  resources :participations, only: [:create]
end
```

### controller:

```
class ConferencesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    @conference = Conference.find params[:id]
  end

  def index
    @conferences = Conference.all
  end
end
```

### rabl template:

rsponse formatted by `index.json.rabl`:

```
collection @conferences
attributes :id, :title
node(:date_from){|c| I18n.l c.date_from, format: :short}
node(:date_to){|c| I18n.l c.date_to, format: :short}
node(:lectures) do |c|
  c.lectures_by_day.map do |l|
    partial 'lectures/base', object: l
  end
end
```

### response

This is the response I get from `http://localhost:3000/conferences.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Ruby on Rails for Dummies",
    "date_from": "11 Dec 12:00",
    "date_to": "13 Dec 17:00",
    "lectures": []
  }
]
```

### backbone model

This is the Backbone model that is supposed to fetch from here:

```
@Mario.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Entities.Conference extends Backbone.Model
    defaults:
      title: ''

  class Entities.ConferenceCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Entities.Conference
    url: '/conferences.json'
```

### ...and finally JS console:

And this is what I get in the end in the js console:

`cc=new Mario.Entities.ConferenceCollection()`

`▹ConferenceCollection {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}`

`cc.fetch()`

At this point rails server responded thusly (from `log/development.log`)

```
2013-12-11T18:07:55+01:00 [ INFO] 40497 : Started GET "/conferences.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-11 18:07:55 +0100
2013-12-11T18:07:55+01:00 [ INFO] 40497 : Processing by ConferencesController#index as JSON
2013-12-11T18:07:55+01:00 [DEBUG] 40497 :   Conference Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conferences".* FROM "conferences"
2013-12-11T18:07:55+01:00 [DEBUG] 40497 :    (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lectures" WHERE "lectures"."conference_id" = 1 AND ("lectures"."date_from" BETWEEN '2013-12-11' AND '2013-12-12')
2013-12-11T18:07:55+01:00 [ INFO] 40497 :   Rendered conferences/index.json.rabl (14.2ms)
2013-12-11T18:07:55+01:00 [ INFO] 40497 : Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 18.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Going back to js console:

`cc.models[0]`

`▹Conference {cid: "c6", attributes: Object, collection: ConferenceCollection, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}`

`cc.models[0].attributes`

```
▽attributes: Object
  ▹_byId: Object
  ▹_onModelEvent: function (event, model, collection, options) {
  ▹_prepareModel: function (attrs, options) {
  ▹_removeReference: function (model) {
  ▹_reset: function () {
  ▹add: function (models, options) {
  ▹all: function () {
  ▹any: function () {
  ▹at: function (index) {
  ▹bind: function (name, callback, context) {
  ▹chain: function () {
  ▹clone: function () {
  ▹collect: function () {
  ...
```

etc. etc.
These are clearly not the defined model attributes.

What on earth is going on? This is supposed to be so simple. I must have missed something, but what? Why is Backbone not interpreting a proper JSON structure as model's attributes?

Comment: yes there is, but `cc.models[0].attributes.models` contains the same object as `cc.models[0]` meaning you can do `cc.models[0].attributes.models[0].attributes` etc. indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

take a look [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#configuration) - this should be interesting for you:

```
config.include_json_root = false
```

I suppose that you have to change this in your config and you should be good to go.

Comment: I always forget about this, but this time it's already been done. Look at the 'response' part of my post, there's no root object there. I triple checked.

Answer (score 0):

As always I spent the entire day trying to fix it and I find a fix after I post a question.

Okay, the problem was nowhere in the aforementioned parts of the application. In my asset pipeline I have included [backbone_rails_sync.js](https://gist.github.com/nakajijapan/3799322) which allows to wrap the attributes in a `paramRoot`, so that when you perform `model.save()` the parameters that go to rails controller look like this:

`{"conference"=>{"title"=>"new conference", "category" => "super conferences"}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"conferences"}`

instead of

`{"title"=>"new conference", "category" => "super conferences", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"conferences"}`

And this particular sync patch completely threw me off.

### solution:

After not much deliberation I replaced it with a **different [monkey patch](https://gist.github.com/jumski/1128000)**. Everything works now and my params are still properly wrapped.